# Sphere not rendering in Unity for Google Cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I was following [this](http://bernieroehl.com/360stereoinunity/) blog post on how to implement 360 degree video in `Unity`. At the end, I used `ffmpeg` to split the video into individual frames as recommended. I also set the first frame as the texture for each material on each sphere. The end result looks like this

[bad sphere](http://ran.2hu.moe/lebvdc.png)

The big problem though is that once I build and run it on my phone or just play the scene itself, the sphere simply fails to render. Could this be caused by the texture being the first frame? Or am I making some other sort of error? Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like the UV map of the sphere is broken

Answer (score 0):

Movies in Unity are usually rendered as textures on objects. On mobile the issue becomes that the device only wants to display video in a video player, so the Unity class MovieTexture is not supported.

I am having success circumventing this, and successfully rendering 360-video on the inside of a sphere using a Unity plug-in from the Unity Asset Store called, Easy Movie Texture.

For working on a Mac, here's what I did:

1. Download the Easy Movie Texture plug-in from the Unity Asset Store
2. Open the Demo Sphere demo scene from Assets/EasyMovieTexture/Scene
3. Create a new (empty) Prefab to your project, and drag the Sphere GameObject from the Demo Sphere scene onto the Prefab.
4. Reopen your Cardboard scene and drag the new videosphere prefab into your hierarchy.
5. Open your source 360-video in Quicktime
6. File -> Export -> 720p
7. Change file extension from '.mov' to '.mp4'
8. Drag your new mp4 file into your projects Assets/Streaming Assets directory. Note: don't import through the menu system, as this will force Unity to convert to OGG.
9. On the "Media Player Ctrl" script component of your videosphere GameObject, locate the "Str_File_Name" field and provide the FULL filename of your newly exported video file. Make sure to include the extension as part of the string, "mymovie.mp4".

Pretty sure that's everything. Hope it helps other folks stuck on this problem.

Final note, the video will only render on the device. In the editor you will only see a white texture on the sphere. You have to publish to the device in order to see your awesome 360-video.